# Phpstorm 9 EAP Method "unique" not found in class Illuminate\Support\Fluent

Tags: php, phpstorm, laravel-5

I am working on a website project and I'am using Laravel 5 and PHPStorm 9 EAP.

I created a migration and use this code `$table->string('name')->unique();` and the IDE highlighted the `unique()` and show a message `Method "unique" not found in class Illuminate\Support\Fluent`.

Here is my migration:

```
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('products');
}

}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try PHPStorm 8. PHPStorm 9 is just EAP, not the stable version.
see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Development+Roadmap

Comment: I already tried it but getting the same highted message

Comment: Same issue here, when I do `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();`

Comment: You should report it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com if it's a bug.

Answer (score 13):

Calling `$table->integer('user_id')` returns a new instance of `Illuminate\Support\Fluent`. But the Fluent class does not provide an `unique()` method. Instead it's using PHP magic method `__call`. That's why PHPStorm is complaining.

**Option one** is to tell PHPStorm that `unique()` is a valid method. For this we can add some PHPDoc in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Fluent.php` and tell PHPStorm that `unique()` is a valid method:

```
/**
 * @method unique
 */
class Fluent implements ArrayAccess, Arrayable, Jsonable, JsonSerializable 
{
    // ...
}
```

However I would not suggest modifying files in the /vendor/ folder. Instead create a bug report/pull request on Laravel. Someone already created a pull request for this (https://github.com/illuminate/support/pull/25).

**Option two** is to modify your create method and try to avoid the magic methods on the Fluent interface:

```
Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unique('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Option 1: It's 2017 now and problem still not solved by Laravel's developers. Option 2: feels like "Use your finger to clean your teeth. There is no need in tootbrush" =) Look for other answers in this thread - they will allow you to use magic at a cost of 1 extra file in your project and 1 minute to add it. Good luck

Answer (score 5):

Personally I use a helper PHP class files (like _ide_helper.php) to tell PHPStorm about the methods.

For the Fluent I created the following file to be indexed by the PHPStorm, but not included in actual php files:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support;

/**
 * @method Fluent first()
 * @method Fluent after($column)
 * @method Fluent change()
 * @method Fluent nullable()
 * @method Fluent unsigned()
 * @method Fluent unique()
 * @method Fluent index()
 * @method Fluent primary()
 * @method Fluent default($value)
 * @method Fluent onUpdate($value)
 * @method Fluent onDelete($value)
 * @method Fluent references($value)
 * @method Fluent on($value)
 */
class Fluent {}
```

As a side note, you should then disable warnings about multiply-defined classes, however if you are using IDE Helper module, you should have them already disabled anyway.

Comment: This one works perfectly up to PHP Storm 2017.3. Create file in root folder of your project an call it "_ide_helper_custom.php" and that will do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Updated version for Laravel 5.5

Create a file in your rood directory with name like _ide_helper_custom.php and copy next code into it:

```
<?php

namespace  {
    exit("This file should not be included, only analyzed by your IDE");
}

namespace Illuminate\Support {

    /**
     * @method Fluent first()
     * @method Fluent after($column)
     * @method Fluent change()
     * @method Fluent nullable()
     * @method Fluent unsigned()
     * @method Fluent unique()
     * @method Fluent index()
     * @method Fluent primary()
     * @method Fluent spatialIndex()
     * @method Fluent default($value)
     * @method Fluent onUpdate($value)
     * @method Fluent onDelete($value)
     * @method Fluent references($value)
     * @method Fluent on($value)
     * @method Fluent charset($value)
     * @method Fluent collation($value)
     * @method Fluent comment($value)
     * @method Fluent autoIncrement()
     * @method Fluent storedAs($value)
     * @method Fluent useCurrent()
     * @method Fluent virtualAs($value)
     */
    class Fluent {

    }

}
```

This will force PHP Storm to index the file and correctly suggest methods for chaining. Tested in PHP Storm 2017.3 but should work in all previous and hopefully future versions of IDE.